# Why does this code give me the "Cannot read property 'style' of null" error?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm relatively new to JavaScript so I'm sure this is just something I overlooked. Here's my code:

```
<a class="shop nav" href="#" onclick="shopBar()">Shop</a>
<div class="nav__menu">
    <a class="buy__list" href="#">Shop Stuff</a>
    <a class="buy__list" href="#">Shop Stuff</a>
    <a class="buy__list" href="#">Shop Stuff</a>
    <a class="buy__list" href="#">Shop Stuff</a>
</div>

<style>
    .nav__menu {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
    
<script>
    function shopBar() {
        var x = document.getElementById("nav__menu");
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I click on the `a` tag, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at shopBar (index.html:63)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM495 index.html:20)
```

Thanks for any help you can provide :)

Comment: `var x = document.getElementById("nav__menu");` but you have a class not an id of `nav_menu`

Comment: There is no element with `id` of `nav__menu`. `nav__menu` is a class and you need to select your element based on its class name: `document.getElementsByClassName("nav__menu")[0];`.

Answer (score 4):

You're using document.getElementById() but trying to target the element via its class name. To target an element by classname, use document.getElementsByClassName()
(see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: Thanks! I cant believe I didn't see this.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get an element by id, however no such element has this id, an so getElementWithId returns null, which explains the error

```
<div class="nav__menu"> // change class here to id for your code to work
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way for this to happen if for x to have the value `null`, which means that there is no element with the id `nav__menu`. The problem is that the element has the **class** `nav__menu`, not the id `nav__menu`. Switch the class to id, and you won't have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer, use `<div id="nav__menu">` instead of `<div class="nav__menu">`.

Let me give you more details about this. There are two main ways of naming elements in HTML: using a `class` or `id`. The difference between the two is that `id` is unique. You can only have one element with the same `id`. For a `class`, you can have as much as you want.

So for your case, your code should be

```js
function shopBar() {
  var x = document.getElementById("nav__menu");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.nav__menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="shop nav" href="#" onclick="shopBar()">Shop</a>
<div id="nav__menu">
  <a class="buy__list" href="#">Shop Stuff</a>
  <a class="buy__list" href="#">Shop Stuff</a>
  <a class="buy__list" href="#">Shop Stuff</a>
  <a class="buy__list" href="#">Shop Stuff</a>
</div>
```